# How can I run using mysql Workbench and xampp together on the same port?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

Having problems with running workbench and xampp, I keep getting blocked port 3306 in xampp.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the port, since one service is already using it the other is blocking it, go into the my.ini file and change the port to 3307 and restart mysql to see if it works, maybe you will need to change the port to 3307 in xampp/php/php.ini